# Compiling Qt for iOS (UIKit lighthouse)

Tags: ios, qt, uikit, lighthouse

I've been trying to compile Qt for iOS, but I've been having some crazy problems that noone else seems to be having (at least according to what I read in the past day).

I followed the instructions from this article:[article url](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/08/09/update-on-uikit-lighthouse-platform/)

1. I cloned a the latest Qt 4.8 from git: `$ git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git`
2. I made the `qt-lighthouse-ios-simulator` folder, cd to it.
3. I ran the long line of code from the article: `$ ../qt/configure -qpa -xplatform qpa/macx-iphonesimulator-g++ -arch i386 -developer-build -release -opengl es2 -no-accessibility -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-phonon-backend -no-svg -no-webkit -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc -no-cups -no-iconv -no-dbus -static -nomake tools -nomake demos -nomake docs -nomake examples -nomake translations`
4. `o`pensource license
5. `yes` I accept the agreement

I get these errors:

`In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/Accessibility.h:13,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/HIServices.h:49,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:34,
                 from generators/mac/pbuilder_pbx.cpp:56:
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65: error: CGCharCode has not been declared
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65: error: CGKeyCode has not been declared`

After struggling with this, searching here and there, and finding nothing useful (even nothing about what CGKeyCode or CGCharCode actually are, I decided to "hack" it and just added the definitions to pbuilder_pbx.cpp:

`typedef u_int16_t    CGCharCode;   /* Character represented by event, if any */
typedef u_int16_t    CGKeyCode;     /* Virtual keycode for event */`

Then another file couldn't compile, with the same errors. After adding them to a couple of files, I eventually added them to qcore_mac_p.h, then some files complained that they didn't know what u_int16_t was, so I added

`typedef unsigned short u_int16_t;  /* compile, god damn you!!! */`

to the same header.

Now everything compiled but there was this linker error:

`ld: in /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64`

Here's where I'm stuck. Any help?

Additional information:

- gcc --version : i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1
- iOS SDK: I have both 4.2 and 4.3
- OS X version: 10.6.7
- Xcode version (if it matters): 4.0.2

Comment: Sounds like somewhere is missing an `#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` and `-framework CoreGraphics` on the linker options.

Comment: @JakePetroules After manually adding `-framework CoreGraphics` to the linker line, here's what I got: `ld: warning: ignoring file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture x86_64 in file` and then the error from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem somehow magically doesn't exist, when I tried the same thing on a different Mac with OS X 10.7.1

I have no idea how and why, but now qmake compiles and links.

Comment: ... which presented me with [this problem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/12682), but at least it can be fixed with some changes to Qt

Comment: and then it lead me to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891839/compiling-qt-for-ios-uikit-lighthouse-part-2)... so, honestly, I don't know how much of a solution this is.