# Compiling Qt for iOS (UIKit lighthouse) part 2

Tags: ios, qt, uikit

I'm trying to compile Qt for the iOS simulator, as explained in [this article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/08/09/update-on-uikit-lighthouse-platform/).

At first I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847836/compiling-qt-for-ios-uikit-lighthouse) but after it (kinda) solved itself I had some more.

First I kept getting this error after executing the first command, which is supposed to build qmake (`../qt/configure ... etc etc`):

`The OpenGL ES 2.0 functionality test failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2, QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 in /Qt/qt/mkspecs/qpa/macx-iphonesimulator-g++.`

Since I knew that I had the 4.3 SDK, I delved into it some more, analyzed the configure script, and after some tracing I saw that the Makefile generated by qmake, required g++-4.2 (which I didn't have), so I just `ln -s g++ g++-4.2` and `ln -s gcc gcc-4.2` in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/`.

I'm not sure if the aforementioned steps matter, that's why I'm writing about them. Anyway, with that, the configure step was successful. Now I ran `make`. After some successfully compiled files I got this:

```
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/WebServicesCore.framework/Headers/WebServicesCore.h:15,
from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:37,
from ../../include/QtCore/private/../../../../qt/src/corelib/kernel/qcore_mac_p.h:83,
from ../../include/QtCore/private/qcore_mac_p.h:1,
from /Qt/qt/src/corelib/tools/qlocale_mac.mm:49:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/WebServicesCore.framework/Headers/WSMethodInvocation.h:759: 
error: 'CFXMLTreeRef' has not been declared
```

The same error appears several more times, from several different lines of WebServicesCore.h. So, basically, here's where I'm stuck now.

Any help? Again?...

Edit: Absolutely, 100% the same thing happens when I configure and try to make Qt for the device (as opposed to the simulator)

Additional info:

- gcc --version : i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
- iOS SDK: I have both 4.3 and 5
- OS X version: 10.7.2
- Xcode version (if it matters): 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to add `-nomake tools` and other `-nomake ...` to your configure ?

Try poking this guys: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/08/09/update-on-uikit-lighthouse-platform/

Comment: This is my full config command line: `../qt/configure -qpa -xplatform qpa/macx-iphonesimulator-g++ -arch i386 -developer-build -release -opengl es2 -no-accessibility -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-phonon-backend -no-svg -no-webkit -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc -no-cups -no-iconv -no-dbus -static -nomake tools -nomake demos -nomake docs -nomake examples -nomake translations`

Comment: Then I have no idea why you get this error. Try poking Qt guys from post I gave you

Comment: The comments are closed over there.

Comment: damn, didn't notice that. I've read somwhere that this compilation error indicates some target platform issues. they suggested to include CFXMLNode.h